# Xcode throws 'atomic_notify_one<unsigned long>' is unavailable

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, xcode12beta6

I installed Xcode 12 on my Mac, tried building my react native app that runs perfectly on android, and get `'atomic_notify_one<unsigned long>' is unavailable`. This is the most information I get from the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error was an error from flipper. Flipper threw several more less descriptive errors that I had to comment it on my podfile. After commenting, this error stopped.

Comment: Yes it is working without flipper and i am able to debug it then what is use of flipper in react native ?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari It's not necessary. It's basically a set of debugging tools like log viewer, stacktrace finder

Answer (score 172):

Instead of commenting out flipper here is a solution that worked for me.

Update flipper in your Podfile to look like this

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

Run `pod repo update` inside the ios folder

And finally, update your project pods using

`pod install`

Comment: Absolutely this worked for me without sacrificing flipper. Than you.

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks. At least iOS development isn't full of unnecessary complexity or anything.

Comment: This setting worked for me with xCode 13.0 : `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.96.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '~> 2.6', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '~> 1.4' })`

Comment: where to add this line?

Comment: @FaizUlHassan After `permissions_path` section.

Comment: This alone didn't solve the issue for me. Took a couple of hours, but eventually [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-829536845) helped me (each and every step)

Answer (score 41):

This issue happened again today after the iOS simulators were updated to iOS 14.5. The answer posted by "Shared S Katre" seems to be a good work-around.

Because React-Native is open source code, I would think that any big updates on iOS can definitely bring about breaking changes. I imagine those will be fixed later.

Anyways - the issue does seem to be with Flipper, which serves as a debugging tool for RN (https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/03/26/version-0.62).

If you just need to get your project to build, you can just simply comment out flipper in your podfile, and re-install your pods like so.

**Podfile**

```
# Enables Flipper.
#
# Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
# you should disable the next line.
# use_flipper!()
```

Next, re-install your pods. I cd'd into the root of the project and used npx.

```
$ npx pod-install
```

Last, try building and running your project:

```
$ npx react-native run-ios
```

Update:

Per the comments, looks like this has been fixed now. If you want flipper, you should be able to revert your Podfile and update flipper.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67314652/9906042

Thanks Stackers!

Comment: Here's the relevant GitHub issue from Flipper– looks like they are working to get a solution in place ASAP.

https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2215

Comment: Theres a patch available for this now with flipper -folly 2.5.3
https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2215#issuecomment-828815200

Answer (score 22):

1. Fix Podfile as shown in below image
   [image]
2. cd ios
3. delete Pods folder and Podfile.lock
4. pod install
5. pod update
6. cd .. && npx react-native run-ios

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution, as other people might be using the Flipper dev tools. This solution is better as it updates the library to include the upstream fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66876338/4160784

Answer (score 17):

If someone has still this error (I have just updated Mac, Xcode, etc), you can fix the build without disabling Flipper and Hermes; in your Pod file under `post_install` just add (I have found it somewhere on the web and changed it to fix new errors with the last updates):

```
post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    react_native_post_install(installer)

    # # to build for the simulator on Apple M1
    # installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    #   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    #     # disables arm64 builds for the simulator
    #     config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
    #   end
    # end

    ## Fix for XCode 12.5 & RN 0.62.2 - See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28405
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
      "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")

    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
      "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")

    ## Fix for Flipper-Folly on iOS 14.5
    find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
      "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)")

    find_and_replace("Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
      "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)")

    find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
      "atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)", "folly::atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)")
  end
```

Before your `target`, add

```
# fixes for last Mac updates
def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

Comment: if the above throws error `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h` then removing `Pods` folder fixes it

Comment: Only this one worked for me! Thanks! Delete Pods file before running pod-install

Comment: On May 19, the bottom 3 replaces are not needed anymore, only leave the the first 2 find_and_replace calls before ## Fix for Flipper-Folly on iOS 14.5 comment.

Comment: I am getting this error : undefined method `flipper_post_install' for #<Pod::Podfile:

Answer (score 13):

I have to comment all `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` in AppDelegate.m, set hermes to false and comment Flipper in Podfile.

After all, delete Pods and Podfile.lock, then pod install

Comment: Your suggestion to disable hermes `:hermes_enabled => false` was what I was missing in order to get to work. Hopefully an update will come out soon. Thanks!

Comment: I had `:hermes_enabled => true` and also needed to change it to `:hermes_enabled => false`. I did `pod install --update-repo` after and it did dix it. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

just commented this line and solved this issue-

```
  # use_flipper!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue when building in XCode 12.5. If temporarily disabling Flipper is not an option for you, you can downgrade to XCode 12.4. This fixed it for me. You can download XCode 12.4 here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more

Comment: Hi @benoit your solution is the only thing that worked without making any changes to any code or dependency. Xcode 12.5 was showing n number of errors one after the other even after fixing them but downgrading to Xcode 12.4 was able to run the app without any changes. Thank you so much for this wonderful suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

To expand a little bit on the Umang's and opensw answers.

I have updated find_and_replace as following. Note, I have added `system("chmod +w " + name)` that fixes `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen` error.

```rb
def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)

      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          system("chmod +w " + name)
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

Here is my flipper configuration

```rb
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

And as for fixing files, in my case, on the most recent versions as of Apr. 30th it is enough to update `DistributedMutex-inl.h` in only one place.

Also, note how I added two extra whitespace symbols before the function name. This is needed so pod install won't break code on the subsequent calls.

```rb
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    react_native_post_install(installer)

    find_and_replace("Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
          "  atomic_notify_one(state);", "  folly::atomic_notify_one(state);")
  end
```

Comment: This worked for me with Expo 44 and Xcode 13.4.1. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer provided by @opensw will work but I have found something more enhanced solution so that it works with pod install every time without deleting the `Pods` folder.
First of all, change add/Replace this line in your Podfile

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

Now in the latest versions mentioned in the above lines fixes an issue with the `Flipper-folly`
But We also need to take care of the RCT-folly and for that, we will use the `find_and_replace` function.
Here is the new function which I got from the [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-828499217)

```
# Define find-and-replace function
  def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
    Dir[dir].each do |name|
        text = File.read(name)
        replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
        replaced = text.index(replacestr)
        if replaced == nil && text != replace
            puts "Fix: " + name
            File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
            STDOUT.flush
        end
    end
    Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
  end
```

Now call this function from the post-install so we will need to add the following 2 function calls inside   `post_install do |installer|`

```
 find_and_replace("Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
                   "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)")

  find_and_replace("Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
  "atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)", "folly::atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)")
```

Here is my Answer in [Github](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2215#issuecomment-829053571)

Answer (score 5):

Replace all current flipper code in your Podfile with this base on your React Native version:

```
add_flipper_pods!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

or

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

Then update for Pods project using this:

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to comment below Flipper code in Podfile:

```
use_flipper!
post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue upgrading a project from RN 0.63 to 0.64 (and using Xcode 12.5), but the top voted answer didn't solve the issue for me, and I was keen to avoid any additional scripts.

I noticed in the [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.3&to=0.64.2) some changes in the podfile - particularly the change from `flipper_post_install(installer)` to `react_native_post_install(installer)`.  I made this change and blitzed my pods directory and then ran `pod install --repo-update` and this fixed it for me :)

I also noticed a patch being run for the `DistributedMutex` file (which was the file in question) after the pods were installed, so it seems to me that this should be the correct fix

**Bonus**: This also allowed me to remove the old `flipper_post_install` script I had at the top of my podfile from a previous upgrade

Answer (score 1):

replace atomic_nofiy_one with folly::atomic_notify_one, the full podfile is blow:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!
  version = '~> 0.33.1'
  pod 'FlipperKit', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
end

# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'AwesomeProject' do
  # Pods for AwesomeProject
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'AwesomeProjectTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  add_flipper_pods!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    ## Fix for XCode 12.5 beta
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
        "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
    "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")
    find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
             "  atomic_notify_one(state);", "  folly::atomic_notify_one(state);")
  end
end

target 'AwesomeProject-tvOS' do
  # Pods for AwesomeProject-tvOS

  target 'AwesomeProject-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
        text = File.read(name)
        replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)

        if text != replace
            puts "Fix: " + name
            File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
            STDOUT.flush
        end
    end
    Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```