# React Native / iOS SDK. No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass' after update iOS SDK to 14.5

Tags: ios, react-native, sdk, xcode12.5, ios14.5

I have updated the iOS SDK platform to version **14.5**. The Xcode version is now **12.5**. After updating, I cannot launch the application on my device. And the compiler throws an error:

> No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass'

I tried reinstalling the pods but it didn't help. How can fix it? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I put together all the proposed solutions and got a working version.

**Podfile**

```
post_install do |installer|
    ## Fix for XCode 12.5
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")
  end
def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

After that I got a new error which is related to Flipper:

```
Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h:1051:5: 'atomic_notify_one<unsigned long>' is unavailable
```

I used the solution from [Xcode throws 'atomic_notify_one' is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286470/4512868) to fix this problem.

```
# Enables Flipper.
#
# Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
# you should disable the next line.
# use_flipper!()
```

And commented out the line `# flipper_post_install(installer)` inside `post_install do |installer|`

Last, re-install your pods, rebuil and run your project.

Comment: It might be worth noting that you'll also need to comment out any Flipper object initializations in the AppDelegate file as well.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the "-" in react-native on the first find_and_replace call for the RCTCxxBridge.mm file.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. But can you share us what is the issue? Why it occurred? And what the proposed solution has managed to fix?

Comment: If you're still experiencing issues (I did with Xcode 13) then the first comment on this answer which explains putting both fix_and_replace onto a single line worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68245484/2061520

Comment: That solved my issue. I had to disable Flipper completely to make it work!

Answer (score 72):

Put this code at the bottom of your ios/Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  ## Fix for XCode 12.5
      find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
      "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
      find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
      "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))")
  end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

save it, do a `pod install` on terminal and try to run/build your project again!

Comment: Tried it, I'm using 0.62.2 version of react native, it did not solve the issue. Getting error - No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass'

Comment: @Vasanth you can solve this issue?

Comment: This did work for me with react native 61.5.  But I consider it an ultra-hack that is madness to do, every time you run something like yarn-update you have to re-run pod install to hotpatch your react code all over again.  Madness.  But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me `React Native - 0.61.5` in 2022 Feb

Comment: yep worked for me too, super thanks

Answer (score 28):

My post_install function had to be slightly different (using `strongModule` instead of `module` in the second replace):

```
  post_install do |installer|
    ## Fix for XCode 12.5
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
    "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
    "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")
  end
```

Comment: I am still unable to build after making those changes and getting this error :
```Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h:1051:5: 'atomic_notify_one<unsigned long>' is unavailable```

Comment: @AnuneetAnand i have the same error. I used the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286470/4512868

Comment: That's a different issue, and need to disable flipper in the Podfile as well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66189325/xcode-throws-atomic-notify-oneunsigned-long-is-unavailable

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly for `Xcode 12.5.1` with `React Native 0.62.2` on my side, while I do the file changes in `patch-package` instead of post_install function.

Comment: You are great! It helped. thanks

Answer (score 15):

After updating to Xcode 13.1, I started getting that issue! However, the famous fix that's shared everywhere (RN GitHub issues and here on StackOverflow) didn't work for me but needed a little change!

`RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))` should change to `RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))`

and `RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))` to `RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))`

As you can see, the given variable name was changed at least in the React Native version I have.

The final code should be looking like this:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
     # Fix after updating to Xcode 13.1
     find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
    "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
    "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")
end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
    Dir[dir].each do |name|
        text = File.read(name)
        replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
        if text != replace
            puts "Fix: " + name
            File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
            STDOUT.flush
        end
    end
    Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me.

Step 1: Open RCTCxxBridge.mm search this code:

```
- (NSArray<RCTModuleData *> *)_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules
                               withDispatchGroup:(dispatch_group_t)dispatchGroup
                                lazilyDiscovered:(BOOL)lazilyDiscovered
```

And change in to this

```
- (NSArray<RCTModuleData *> *)_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules
                               withDispatchGroup:(dispatch_group_t)dispatchGroup
                                lazilyDiscovered:(BOOL)lazilyDiscovered
```

Step 2: Open RCTTurboModuleManager.mm (line 300) and change
`RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))` to `RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the one part that I was missing! Xcode now builds properly for me as well

Comment: For me, these files were located at: `./node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm` and `./node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm`