# How to migrate to Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I'm not able to build a React Native project, which built correctly using Xcode 11, using Xcode 12.5.

I can no longer use Xcode 11 because only more current versions of Xcode carry the necessary API to publish/upload to TestFlight and the app store.

Now I get three build errors:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *' with an rvalue of type 'NSArray<Class> *'

Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *' with an rvalue of type 'NSArray<Class> *'

Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *' with an rvalue of type 'NSArray<Class> *'
```

I also noticed that deployment targets were automatically upgraded from 10 and 9:

```
- IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 9.0;
+ IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.1;
```

Some new properties were added related to Clang:

```
+ CLANG_ANALYZER_LOCALIZABILITY_NONLOCALIZED = YES;
```

How can I configure the project to deploy this app using Xcode 12.5?

$ react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
OS: macOS 11.3
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8100B CPU @ 3.60GHz
Memory: 256.45 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 10.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.21.1 - ~/npm-global/bin/yarn
npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 14.5, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 14.5, watchOS 7.4
IDEs:
Xcode: 12.5/12E262 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: ^16.11.0 => 16.12.0
react-native: 0.61.4 => 0.61.4
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: At this point, it seems that the best answer is likely to upgrade React Native, but even then there are likely unfortunate consequences in that path. Upgrading RN means not having to use a solution of find and replace, but I have different build errors now.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I fixed this by changing a parameter cast in the React module RCTCxxBridge.mm like so:

```
- (NSArray<RCTModuleData *> *)_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules
                               withDispatchGroup:(dispatch_group_t)dispatchGroup
                                lazilyDiscovered:(BOOL)lazilyDiscovered
```

To:

```
- (NSArray<RCTModuleData *> *)_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules
                               withDispatchGroup:(dispatch_group_t)dispatchGroup
                                lazilyDiscovered:(BOOL)lazilyDiscovered
```

I am running 0.59 and not using CocoaPods, but the basic fix is that casts of the form:

```
NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules
```

Should be replaced with:

```
NSArray<Class> *)modules
```

Comment: I had edited my above response to be I belive the fix, rather than saying I had the same issue with Xcode 12.5.

Comment: After using this fix all the old errors are removed but one error manifests, `NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>>`, on line 300 of `RCTTurboModuleManager.mm`.

Comment: @haleonj, please refer to this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28405#issuecomment-827424477. You have to change RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module)) to RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module))) as well

Comment: Can you add "You have to change RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module)) to RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module))) as well" please? I want to mark the answer once it's complete.

Comment: Worked for me as well running RN 60.6

Answer (score 29):

This one worked for me.

1. Open **RCTCxxBridge.mm** (line 770)  and change parameter type from: `(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules` to `(NSArray<Class> *)modules`
2. Open **RCTTurboModuleManager.mm** (line 300) and change from:
   `RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))` to `RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)));`

Answer (score 13):

This one worked for me. Update the PODFILE with:

```
post_install do |installer|
    ## Fix for XCode 12.5 beta
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
    "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
end
```

And at the end of podfile add a function:

```
def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

The last step if to run:

```
pod install
```

Comment: This worked for me. I like this more than the other answers because it doesn't require directly modifying the .mm files, which could be overwritten the next time you run npm install. Related react-native issue report: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31412#issuecomment-828097064

Answer (score 7):

i've faced the same issue and after using this script the problem was solved for this three error but faced a new one (No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass')

which was solved by adding this line in the postinstall script

### Fix for XCode 12.5 beta

```
post_install do |installer|

find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
"_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")

find_and_replace("../node_modules/react- 
native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
"RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))", 
"RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))")

end
```

Comment: This worked for me, just a comment about what I had to do in order to make it work: 

1. There's a line break in the second `find_and_replace` which leads to the `RCTTurboModuleManager.mm` file not being updated properly. Using a one-liner fixes this:
`find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))")`

2. The `find_and_replace` function needs to be defined at the end of the `Podfile` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in Xcode and go to File > Workspace settings > Build System > Legacy Build System

Comment: Did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Xcode 13.1. But I resolved the problem with this [method](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28405#issuecomment-779382959).