# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen while running react native build on Jenkins

Tags: ios, react-native, docker, continuous-integration, cocoapods

[image]

Here is a content of my `Podfile`.

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'test' do
  use_unimodules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config["reactNativePath"],
    :hermes_enabled => true
    )

  def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
    Dir[dir].each do |name|
        text = File.read(name)
        replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
        if text != replace
            puts "Fix: " + name
            File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
            STDOUT.flush
        end
    end
    Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
  end

   # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/67308343/10540870
    ## Fix for XCode 12.5 & RN 0.62.2 - See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28405
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
      "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")

    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
      "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")

    find_and_replace("Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
      "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)")

    find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
      "atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)", "folly::atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)")

  end

  # Other native modules

end
```

I can build the project locally. Both, ios and android run is great. But I've got this issue while running the docker build. I got this on a first local run as well but this one has dissappeared after removing Pods and reinstalling these. Docker image is doing the same algorithm but this error keeps coming.